# Express.js large file download freezes / hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download

I'm having some trouble with downloading large CSV files from a Node.js Express server, which freezes / hangs at times in the browser. I'm using the `res.sendFile()` function on the server (using `res.download` also yields the same issue). The network tab does not report any errors when the download is triggered in the browser. Is there anything important that I'm missing here?

**Server-side js:**

```
        try {
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/csv');
            res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment;filename=${filename}`);
            res.sendFile(filename); 
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            res.send(e).end(); //ERROR
            return;
        }
```

**Client js:**

```
let anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
anchorElement.href = '/report/' + report_id + '/download';
anchorElement.download = export_filename;
anchorElement.target = '_blank';
document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
anchorElement.click();
```

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]